# Is there a way to add models to postgres without deleting all the tables in postgres?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

Django
I am trying to add a new table/model from Django models to my existing postgres database with tables already but the only solution is to start from scratch again

Solution:
Delete migrations, delete all the tables in the postgres database. python manage.py makemigrations, python manage.py migrate

Error:
The table does not exist when browsing the drf api or the postgres database after trying to makemigrations and migrate with the new models.

Comment: If you ran migrations, the table would exist. There is no need to delete all the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Adding additional tables (as a result of creating new models) does not require you to start from scratch or delete any existing data. It would be helpful to have examples of the migrations which fail to apply.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your migration files and migrations in the database (djang_migrations table - i hope it is correct table name) are not compatible.

If you are sure that your tables in db and your models are the same (existing migration files mirrors your database tables) and you want **SomeModel** (for this example) model to be created you can try to:

1. Clear your django_migrations table - remember to make backup of this table
2. manage.py migrate --fake (it will only create some rows in django_migrations table)
3. manage.py makemigrations (it should create migration file for **SomeModel** model)
4. manage.py migrate (it will create new table)

Hope it will help :)